# how to backport this code from version 3.3 to version 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to do one assignment in python. I have made it. But since the software that used in my class is in version 2.7 , then I need to run my codes from python 3.3 to 2.7. The codes works well in version 3.3 but not in 2.7. therefore can you guys please help me with this?
This is my codes.

```
# selectRobot.py #  # 2014-03-26 #

 '''
  The output will be like below:

  what type of robot application you like choose?
  a) assembly
  b) spot welding

  Then let say the customer choose a or b, it will go to next question:

  2.How much the load you expect for the robot to carry?
  a) 0-2 kg
  b) 0-5 kg

   And so on ...

  This is just a start ... need to continue ...
  until finished choosing all attributes of the desired robot.

  '''
  from __future__ import print_function
  menu1 = \
  '''Please choose the type of robot application ?
  a) assembly
  b) spot welding
  Please enter a or b    :  '''

  menu2 = \
  '''What is the max load for this robot?
  a) 0-5   kg
  b) 6-10  kg
  c) 11-15 kg
  Please enter a, b or c :  '''

  menu3 = \
 '''What is the reach for this robot?
  a) 0-1 m
  b) 1-2 m
  Please enter a or b    :  '''

  menu4 = \
  '''What is the mounting for this robot?
  a) floor
  b) wall
  Please enter a or b    :  '''

  def showMenuGetChoice( menu, low, high ):
  while True:
       reply = input( menu ).lower()
        if low <= reply and reply <= high:
            return reply
        else:
            print( "'", reply, "' was NOT in valid " \
                   'input range ', low, '..', high, sep = '' )

 modelsStr = [] # get empty list to hold models
 solns = [] # get empty list to hold all possible solution lists
 count = 0

 for i, a in enumerate(['a', 'b']):
    for j, b in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
        for k, c in enumerate(['a', 'b']):
            for m, d in enumerate(['a', 'b']):
                count += 1
                modelsStr.append( 'model_' + str(count) )
                solns.append( [a,b,c,d])

     # print( modelsStr )


 def mainLoop():
    robot_specs = [] # get an empty list

    robot_specs.append( showMenuGetChoice( menu1, 'a', 'b' ))

    robot_specs.append( showMenuGetChoice( menu2, 'a', 'c' ))

    #print( 'So far, robot_specs =', robot_specs )

    robot_specs.append( showMenuGetChoice( menu3, 'a', 'b' ))

    robot_specs.append( showMenuGetChoice( menu4, 'a', 'b' ))

    #print( 'So far, robot_specs =', robot_specs )

    for i, lst in enumerate( solns ):
        if lst == robot_specs:
            print( robot_specs, '==>', modelsStr[i] )
            return
    print( 'There was an unexpected error ...' ) 


more = True
while( more ):
    mainLoop()
    reply = input( '\nMore (y/n) ? ' ).lower()
    if reply == 'n':
        more = False
        input( "Press 'Enter' to continue/exit ... " )
```

Comment: You don't want an answer for a problem, but you want let others to do your task, thus you get now a -1 and a moderator flag from me.

Comment: Your indentation is *all over the place*; as it stands your code won't even run. It's too large a piece to go and just fix up here.

Comment: Your **only** problem is the `input()` function; you already use `from __future__ import print_function`, replace `input()` with `raw_input()` and you are there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted (apart from post indentation problems too severe to fix by hand) is almost entirely Python 2 ready. You already use `from __future__ import print_function` to handle the `print()` functions.

The only thing that remains is the `input()` function; in Python 2, `input()` is a combination of `raw_input()` and `eval()`; replace all `input()` calls with `raw_input()` and your code should run on Python 2 just fine.